# Laravel 5.7 Show all values from database column with dynamic drop down menu

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel 5.7 application I have a dynamic drop down menu that calls distinct values from a database column. The drop down is in a form for users to filter their records on a record summary page. The selection values are going to the (get) query string correctly and the records are being retrieved correctly into a table in a blade view.  What I can't work out is how to retrieve all values from the drop down menu, for instance with an "all" default value at the start of the drop down menu, if users don't want to select a single value. If the user selects the default value - "all" - this should return all records regardless of their priority. Any guidance will be most appreciated.

**Controller**

```
public function summary(Request $request)
{
  $priorities = DB::table('tasks')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->distinct()->orderBy('priority', 'asc')->pluck('priority');

  $priority = $request->query('priority');
  $end = $request->query('end');
  $start = $request->query('start');
  $all = $request->query('priority' == "all"){
  DB::table('tasks')->pluck('priority')};

  $result = DB::table('tasks')
              ->whereBetween('date', array($start, $end))
              ->where('priority', '=', $priority || $all)
              ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
              ->orderBy('priority', 'asc')
              ->get();

  return view('/summary', compact('priorities', 'result'));
}
```

**View**

```
<label for="distance">Priority:</label><br> 
<select class="form-control" name="priority" id="priority"> 
  <option value="all">---ALL---</option>
  @foreach ($priorities as $priority)
  <option value ="{{ $priority }}">{{ $priority }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

If the user selects the default value - "all" - this should return all records regardless of their priority.

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page then you should use `ajax` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the value you get from request like

```
$priority = $request->query('priority');

 $result = DB::table('tasks')
 ->whereBetween('date', array($start, $end))
 ->where('user_id', auth()->id())

  if($priority=="all"){
   $result = $result->where('priority', '=',$all);
  }else{
   $result = $result->where('priority', '=', $priority );
  }

  $result = $result->orderBy('priority', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you - that helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = document.getElementById("priority");
var all = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

if(all === "all") {
    var base_url = 'http://localhost/laravel/get-priority'
 $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url : base_url+"/all",
          data : dataString,
          success : function(data){
             $.each(data, function(key, value){
                       // alert(key);
                        $('#priority').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">' + value.priority+ '</option>');

                    });
          }
}
```

and in your controller

```
 $priority = $request->query('priority');

 $result = DB::table('tasks')
     ->whereBetween('date', array($start, $end))
     ->where('user_id', auth()->id());


  if($priority=="all"){
      $all = $request->query('distance' == "all"){
          DB::table('sessions')->pluck('distance');
      }
      $result = $result->where('priority', '=',$all);
  }else{
      $result = $result->where('priority', '=', $priority );
  }

  $result = $result->orderBy('priority', 'asc')
            ->get();
```